# In Swift can we combine JSONSerialization and JSONDecoder When making api calls

Tags: swift

Is there a way were I can combine these two function to have only one function. The reason I have 2 function is because one function allows me to use a Codable struct when I call the function to make api call. The other function allows me to make api call then later emit (I'm using socket.io) the data without decoding it.

I am hoping to have a way that I can have 1 function that will allow me to do both

Example 1 of how I am calling function

```
let url = "https://remote-production.up.railway.app/getRoomId"
        let apiService = APIService(urlString: url)
        Task.detached {
            do {
                let response: RoomId = try await apiService.getJSON()
            }
        }
```

Example 2 of how I am calling function

```
 Task {
                do {
                    let responseData: [String: Any] = try await apiService. getSerializationJSON()
                    let dataToSend: [String: Any] = ["requestId": requestId, "response": responseData]
                    /// Emit event back to server client
                    self.socket.emit("host_response", dataToSend)
                    self.userSettings.recentConnections.append(userIp) // Add userIp to recentConnections list
                } catch {
                    print("There was an error with the API request: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                }
            }
```

ApiService.swift:

```
import Foundation

class APIService {
    let urlString: String
    let headersDict: [String: String]
    
    init(urlString: String, headersDict: [String: String] = [:]) {
        self.urlString = urlString
        self.headersDict = headersDict
    }
    
    func getSerializationJSON() async throws -> [String: Any] {
        guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else {
            throw APIError.invalidURL
        }
        
        // Setup request object: example headers, methods, etc
        var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
        
        // Set custom headers if available
        headersDict.forEach { key, value in
            urlRequest.setValue(value, forHTTPHeaderField: key)
        }
        
        do {
            let (data, response) = try await URLSession.shared.data(for: urlRequest)
            guard let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpResponse.statusCode == 200 else {
                throw APIError.invalidResponseStatus
            }
            
            do {
                let decodedDictionary = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String: Any]
                guard let jsonDictionary = decodedDictionary else {
                    throw APIError.corruptData
                }
                return jsonDictionary
            } catch {
                throw APIError.decodingError(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        } catch {
            throw APIError.dataTaskError(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
    
    func getJSON<T: Decodable>(dateDecodingStrategy: JSONDecoder.DateDecodingStrategy = .deferredToDate,
                               keyDecodingStrategy: JSONDecoder.KeyDecodingStrategy = .useDefaultKeys) async throws -> T {
        guard
            let url = URL(string: urlString)
        else {
            throw APIError.invalidURL
        }
        do {
            let (data, response) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: url)
            guard
                let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse,
                httpResponse.statusCode == 200
            else {
                throw APIError.invalidResponseStatus
            }
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = dateDecodingStrategy
            decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = keyDecodingStrategy
            do {
                let decodedData = try decoder.decode(T.self, from: data)
                return decodedData
            } catch {
                throw APIError.decodingError(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        } catch {
            throw APIError.dataTaskError(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
}

enum APIError: Error, LocalizedError {
    case invalidURL
    case invalidResponseStatus
    case dataTaskError(String)
    case corruptData
    case decodingError(String)
    
    var errorDescription: String? {
        switch self {
        case .invalidURL:
            return NSLocalizedString("The endpoint URL is invalid", comment: "")
        case .invalidResponseStatus:
            return NSLocalizedString("The API failed to issue a valid response.", comment: "")
        case .dataTaskError(let string):
            return string
        case .corruptData:
            return NSLocalizedString("The data provided appears to be corrupt", comment: "")
        case .decodingError(let string):
            return string
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way in my opinion is to separate responsibilities, have one function that downloads and returns `Data` and separate functions for decoding the data

```
func fetch(from urlString: String) async throws -> Data  {
    guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else {
        throw APIError.invalidURL
    }
    var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
    headersDict.forEach { key, value in
        urlRequest.setValue(value, forHTTPHeaderField: key)
    }
    do {
        let (data, response) = try await URLSession.shared.data(for: urlRequest)
        guard let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpResponse.statusCode == 200 else {
            throw APIError.invalidResponseStatus
        }

        return data
    } catch {
        throw APIError.dataTaskError("\(error)")
    }
}
```

Serialisation

```
func serializationJSON(data: Data) throws -> [String: Any] {
    do {
        let decodedDictionary = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String: Any]
        guard let jsonDictionary = decodedDictionary else {
            throw APIError.corruptData
        }
        return jsonDictionary
    } catch {
        throw APIError.decodingError("\(error)")
    }
}
```

Decoding

```
func decode<DecodedType: Decodable>(data: Data, dateDecodingStrategy: JSONDecoder.DateDecodingStrategy = .deferredToDate,
                          keyDecodingStrategy: JSONDecoder.KeyDecodingStrategy = .useDefaultKeys) throws -> DecodedType {
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = dateDecodingStrategy
    decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = keyDecodingStrategy
    do {
        let decodedData = try decoder.decode(DecodedType.self, from: data)
        return decodedData
    } catch {
        throw APIError.decodingError("\(error)")
    }
}
```

---

An alternative if you do want it as one function is to pass in the handling (decoding/serialisation) as an argument to the function

```
func fetch<ResultType>(from urlString: String, decodeJson: (Data) throws -> ResultType) async throws -> ResultType  {
    guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else {
        throw APIError.invalidURL
    }
    var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
    headersDict.forEach { key, value in
        urlRequest.setValue(value, forHTTPHeaderField: key)
    }
    do {
        let (data, response) = try await URLSession.shared.data(for: urlRequest)
        guard let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpResponse.statusCode == 200 else {
            throw APIError.invalidResponseStatus
        }

        do {
            return try decodeJson(data)
        } catch {
            throw APIError.decodingError("\(error)")
        }
    } catch {
        throw APIError.dataTaskError("\(error)")
    }
}
```

Usage example

```
let apiService = APIService(urlString: "bla.bla")

Task {
    let result = try await apiService.fetch(from: "some.url") { data in
//        let decodedDictionary = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String: Any]
//        guard let jsonDictionary = decodedDictionary else {
//            throw APIError.corruptData
//        }
//        return jsonDictionary

        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .iso8601
        do {
            let decodedData = try decoder.decode(RoomId.self, from: data)
            return decodedData
        } catch {
            throw APIError.decodingError("\(error)")
        }

    }
}
```